# OOP and Fortran90

Tags: oop, fortran

Hello I am trying to learn Object Oriented Programming using Fortran (all my codes are written in Fortran 90), I partially know C++ but I want to carry on using Fortran.

In Fortran you make classes employing modules. I am facing compiling errors when writing the `integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)` statement. Here goes my academic code. Its a short code that uses Abstract classes

```
module class_Rectangle
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
  type Rectangle
     real(dp) :: a,b
  end type Rectangle
contains
  subroutine area_rectangle(area,info)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(out) :: area
    type(Rectangle), intent(in) ::  info

    area = info%a * info%b

  end subroutine area_rectangle
end module class_Rectangle

program Main
  use class_Rectangle
  use class_Circle
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)

  interface compute_area
     module procedure area_rectangle, area_circle
  end interface compute_area

  type(Rectangle) :: geoA
  type(Circle) :: geoB
  real(dp) :: area

  geoA = Rectangle(2.0d0,4.0d0)
  call area_rectangle(area,geoA)
  write(*,*) 'Rectangle area:', area
  geoB = Circle(1.0d0)
  call area_circle(area,geoB)
  write(*,*) 'Circle area:',area

end program Main
```

The message that the compiler returns me is the following:

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
                          1
```

Error: Name 'dp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'dp' from module 'class_rectangle'
Main.f90:81.13:

```
  real(dp) :: area
         1
```

Error: Name 'dp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'dp' from module 'class_rectangle'
Main.f90:84.30:

Any hint or advice is welcome.

Comment: OOP is normally done using Fortran 2003. Google shows many pages about *something like OOP* in Fortran 90, but that is not real OOP and those tutorials are obsolete in this cetury. Especially if you know C++ you will find those techniques insufficient.

Comment: You have two definitions of `dp` in scope in `main`.  You might think that there is one name with one definition (written twice), but the compiler thinks that there are two definitions for only one name -- ambiguity.  Easy solution is probably to drop the definition in `main`.

Comment: So I assume that its better to define the size of the objects in the class, and not in the main. Is it right @HighPerformanceMark ????

Comment: No, that's not what I meant at all.  And I think you are confusing two different Fortran concept, the `size` and the `kind` of a variable.  Your use of `dp` specifies the `kind` of variables, not their `size`.

Comment: AAAAAA, now I understand your point. I always thought that the kind of variables stores the size of the variables... Will read about that. Thanks @HighPerformanceMark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use `USE` statement with `ONLY`. If you do so, you will not encounter the ambiguity error you get. In addition, you will know exactly what is being used in your code from each module, just by a quick look at the top lines of your code. Therefore, your main program header could look like this:

```
program Main

use class_Rectangle, only: Rectangle, area_rectangle
use class_Circle, only: Circle, area_circle
implicit none


integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)

interface compute_area
        module procedure area_rectangle, area_circle
end interface

type(Rectangle) :: geoA
type(Circle) :: geoB
real(dp) :: area

geoA = Rectangle(2.0d0,4.0d0)
call area_rectangle(area,geoA)
write(*,*) 'Rectangle area:', area
geoB = Circle(1.0d0)
call area_circle(area,geoB)
write(*,*) 'Circle area:',area

end program Main
```

For a good tutorial on OOP programming in Fortran with some good examples, see the book "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf et al.

Comment: In this case I think it would be better to use the dp from the / a module to overcome consistency problems for arguments.

Comment: I think it's poor advice to define `dp` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @King, and thanks for the reference you shared. I am using the book written by Ed Akin... the book is really didactic. Linking always fortran to c++ and other languages.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to work with a code that does have the *Always use USE statement with ONLY* rule. It is a real PITA. It is horrible, especially considering they used loads and loads of global module variables. I don't think the rule is useful. I use `only` quite often, but always as a rule ... just no.

Comment: @AndresValdez That book is completely obsolete.  Modern OOP is done in Fortran 2003 and later. OOP in Fortran 90/95 is completely inadequate and it is no real OOP.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks @VladimirF, will try to look after other material. This one I founded on the fortran wiki-site...

Comment: @VladimirF I don't understand why you would not like ONLY keyword? Could you clarify? To me, it is actually very useful, because it clarifies the dependency of the code to each module.

Comment: I use the keyword all the time but I do not like the strict rule.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler, you should get pretty helpful messages

```
module a
end module a

program b
    implicit none
    use a
end program b
```

And compile:

```
$ gfortran mod_test.F90
mod_test.F90:6:9:

     implicit none
                 2
     use a
         1
Error: USE statement at (1) cannot follow IMPLICIT NONE statement at (2)
```

Comment: True true you are right. I changed that lines, and then updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit:  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
in the main program! By USEing class_Rectangle the main program it 
shares this variable with the module (except you declare it private,
which is not what you want here I guess).

Comment: Interesting it worked, but I was forced to write 'real*8' instead of 'real(dp)' for the area declaration

Comment: @AndresValdez You should not be forced to do it at all if you do it properly. Just make sure you `use` the module that contains the definition of `dp`.